# "гибкий" запрос в Django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm, django-filter

Пытаюсь написать гибкий запрос к БД, в который можно вставлять фильтры из формы, полученной на сайте. То есть количество фильтров может изменятся.
Приведу пример запроса:

```
data = Transactions.objects.values_list(
        'number', 'number__lego__title',
        'number__shop__city__city', 'option__options',
        'number__logistic_company', 'number__deadlines',
        'number__shop__telephone', 'number__regularity__regularity'
    ).filter('Изменяемая часть фильтров').order_by('Изменяемое количество полей')
```

Искал методы реализации, но решений не нашел.
Есть ли способ составить такой запрос, если есть, то как он должен выглядеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте переменное число позиционных и именованных агрументов при вызове функции:

```
filters = {}
filters['number'] = '123'
filters['number__lego__title'] = 'abc'
filters['some_numeric_field__gt'] = 5

order = []
order.append('number')
order.append('-number__lego__title')

data = Transactions.objects.values_list(
        'number', 'number__lego__title',
        'number__shop__city__city', 'option__options',
        'number__logistic_company', 'number__deadlines',
        'number__shop__telephone', 'number__regularity__regularity'
    ).filter(**filters).order_by(*order)
```